# Parameter Value changed automatically in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the following issue in android:

In my project, there is an parameter "CMat" which is loaded from a file at the beginning of the activity. Then there is a thread when the system get a frame from the camera, there is a thread to use this CMat to do some calculation with the image captured by camera. In this thread, I try to trace the size of the CMat and output it. After several outputs, its size suddenly changed(show as follow) and my app crashed(fatal signal 11 sigsegv at some memory location).

```
08-12 13:44:32.868: I/CMat(21267): 128x500
08-12 13:44:35.061: I/CMat(21267): 128x500
08-12 13:44:37.343: I/CMat(21267): 128x500
08-12 13:44:39.565: I/CMat(21267): 128x500
08-12 13:44:41.788: I/CMat(21267): 128x500
08-12 13:44:44.240: I/CMat(21267): 0x0    // sometimes it would turn to a very big size
```

Do anyone know why?

construction OpenCV Mat class:

I try to use a thread to load from file, in this thread, I first loaded it and pass its address to handler. In handler, I reconstruct CMat with this address.

```
//in load file thread:
Mat centerMat = FileIO.ReadMat(path+"center.txt"); 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putLong("centerAddr", centersMat.nativeObj);
msg.setData(bundle);
msg.what = Data_prepare;
Eventhandler.sendMessage(msg);
// in handler:
if (msg.what == Data_prepare) {
CMat = new Mat((long) msg.getData().getLong("centerAddr"));
// in Camera thread
double[] feature = extract(rgba, CMat); // my function to extract feature. I don't change the CMat in my function
```

Comment: Impossible to give constructive feedback without seeing your code.

Comment: Are you attempting to instantiate a new instance of Mat using the pointer from the original instance with this line of code ... CMat = new Mat((long) msg.getData().getLong("centerAddr"));  ?  Are you sure that your original instance centerMat has remained in scope?

Comment: That's what I am concerning. Java recycle mechanism may regard this address as garbage and recycle it after the loading file thread.

Comment: Yes, most likely.  You should move it to a higher level in the app so that it doesn't go out of scope.  It would then become a common resource to all threads that access it.  You should probably wrap access to it in a synchronized block.

Comment: Problem solved as you suggested. I try to initialize CMat in load file thread and it never happens again. Thanks.